# How to create CGColorRef from componets

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a code line

```
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:1.f].CGColor;
```

Can I rewrite it with our using `UIColor`? I mean can I create `CGColorRef` from a, r, g, b components and pass it to `shapeLayer.strokeColor`, considering using ARC.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. I was confused for a moment :)

Comment: Sure, you can create a `CGColorRef` using `CGColorCreate`. You just have to provide a color space and the color components. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGColor/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGColorCreate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid memory leaks you should release `CGColorSpaceRef`

```
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGColorRef aColor = CGColorCreate( colorspace, components ); 
shapeLayer.strokeColor = aColor;
CGColorRelease( aColor );
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
```

Comment: Thank you. Btw, it looks more complex than a single line `shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:1.f].CGColor;`. From performance point of view, which is better?

Comment: Well that is true, because of that it is generally used as '[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor' :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. Try out following

```
CGColorCreate(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), [1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0]) //array values are in order- red, green, blue, alpha
```

Refer https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGColor/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGColorCreate

Comment: OP specified obj-c, you're using a swift array there. You want a C array. You also want to release the color space after using it.